# Signature verified, but "Open File - Security Warning" dialog is raised when executing from the network

Tags: .net, security, code-signing

I've got an executable that I've signed using signtool.exe, and a certificate generated from an enterprise CA. Running signtool verify /pa \path\to\exe returns:

```
Index  Algorithm  Timestamp
========================================
0      sha1       Authenticode

Successfully verified: \\path\to\exe
```

I've added the certificate to the Trusted Publishers store, but when executing it from a network path, I get an "Open File - Security Warning" dialog stating "We can't verify who created this file. Are you sure you want to run this file?"

What do I need to do to allow users to run this without getting that prompt?

Comment: Not on my end. I ended up running the application via a GPO instead of using task scheduler. That seems to bypass the security requirements.